# C - fscanf into a dynamic array crash

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've been tinkering with this program that is a music player in C, but I've run into an issue when reading from a file.

```
typedef struct my_string
{
    char str[256]; // my string contains an array of 255 characters + null
} my_string;

typedef enum music_genre { pop, rock, jazz, classical} music_genre;

typedef struct track_data 
{
    my_string name;
    my_string path;
} track_data;

typedef struct track_array 
{
    int size;
    track_data* trackdata;
} track_array;

typedef struct album_data 
{
    int album_number;
    my_string name;
    my_string artist;
    music_genre genre;
    track_array tracks;
} album_data;

typedef struct albums_data 
{
    int size;
    album_data* data;
} albums_data;

void read_albums_from_file(albums_data* albums)
{
FILE* file_ptr;
int num_of_albums;
int i;
int j;
my_string string;

if ((file_ptr = fopen("albumfile.dat", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Success!\n");
    fscanf(file_ptr, "%d\n", &num_of_albums);
    printf("%d\n", num_of_albums);
    albums->size = num_of_albums;
    albums->data = malloc(sizeof(track_data) * albums->size);
    printf("um\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_albums; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", albums->size);
        albums->data[i].album_number = i + 1;
        printf("um1\n");
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].name);
        printf("um2\n");
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].artist);
        printf("um3\n");
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%d\n", &albums->data[i].genre);
        printf("um4\n");
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%d\n", &albums->data[i].tracks.size);
        printf("um5\n");
        albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata = malloc(sizeof(track_data) * albums->data[i].tracks.size);
        printf("um6\n");

        for (j = 0; j < albums->data[i].tracks.size; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name);
            printf("1");
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].path);
        }

    }

}

}
```

This following section specifically crashes my code:

```
        for (j = 0; j < albums->data[i].tracks.size; j++) //assigns track data to album
        {
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%s", albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name);
            printf("1");
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].path);
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes once it attempts to read the tracks in from the file. I've tried using with and without ampersands, I've used a variable called 'string' and read into that without issue, but here it fails to work. I think I narrowed it down to "albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name" causing the issues. All printf statements are my attempts to troubleshoot.

This is the contents of the file that it's reading from (comments aren't in this file, I added them in to explain)

```
1
Hands All Over
Maroon 5
0 // Genre
1 // # of tracks
Never Gonna Leave This Bed // Title
Desktop // Location
```

I'm not the strongest at using pointers; trying to get over my 'fear' of them through usage.

EDIT: It appears that when I run it through GDB it doesn't crash.

Comment: First off, is the file open?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include the whole procedure: fixed! I ran the program without the file open.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: if it reads a string perfectly using `fscanf(file_ptr, "%s", albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name);` then why do you add ampersands in the real example (note: ampersands is the way, to pass the pointer)

Comment: Current formatting is a mess; that's the section that crashes my code on execution. Made it clearer (I hope). Currently in the process of using GDB, never used it before.

Comment: @RobertCortese no wonder you have 'fears' if you do not use a debugger:) It's essential for the development of any software more complex than 'Hello World'.

Comment: I'm currently going through the program with the debugger (super confusing) but from what I've gathered the value of albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name is rð­-º\ recurring

Comment: 'It appears that when I run it through GDB it doesn't crash' you have undefined behaviour - uninitialized vars, running of end of arrays and the like.  The debugger has likely zeroed something that you should have explicitly zeroed yourself:)

Comment: Okay I found the error using GDB; it didn't work and threw a segmentation fault at me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem; turns out the problem was a segmentation fault. It appears that if I replaced the loop reading in the track locations:

```
for (j = 0; j < albums->data[i].tracks.size; j++)
    {
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].name);
        printf("1");
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &albums->data[i].tracks.trackdata[j].path);
    }
```

with this code instead:

```
for (j = 0; j < albums->data[i].tracks.size; j++)
        {
            read_album_tracks(&albums->data[i].tracks, file_ptr);
        }

void read_album_tracks(track_array* track, FILE* file_ptr)
{
    int j;
    int i;
    track->trackdata = malloc(sizeof(track_data) * track->size);
    for (j = 0; j < track->size; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &track->trackdata[j].tracktitle);
            fscanf(file_ptr, "%255[^\n]%*c", &track->trackdata[j].path);
        }
}
```

Memory allocation wasn't correct; thanks for all the help!